# Excel multiple variable lookup then output a given value

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, match, vlookup

I have two sheets in excel. The first sheet1 has 3 given values (E, fy, f'c), the second sheet2 has all of those same values with corresponding p (rho) values. I'm trying to write a code such as vlookup or similar that first checks for the fy column, then the f'c, then E, and then provides the p value at the intersection of those values. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Basically I should be able to input E = .0075, fy = 60000, f'c = 4000. Then the code should search Sheet2 and find the corresponding rho p value to be = .0138 (Column D, Row 16)

I've attached a google spreadsheet with the example. [spreadsheet example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CeSAKIqfKJcjwdYi8cVCL8ciIvO8X-sHqEkrtFD_Rg0/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use INDEX to Return the correct column then a simple SUMIFS to get the correct number:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(Sheet2!A:F,0,MATCH(B1,Sheet2!$1:$1,0)),Sheet2!A:A,B2,Sheet2!B:B,"=" & B3)
```

[image]

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
=OFFSET(Sheet2!B3,MATCH(B2,Sheet2!A3:A22)-5+MATCH(B3,Sheet2!B3:B7),MATCH(B1,Sheet2!C1:F1))
```

This formula assumes that E always has the same three values for each value of fy.   If not, the match range could be offset based on the fy value.

Comment: I get `#N/A` when looking for E = `p min` or the blank cell.

Comment: Oops, range error (fixed now), and it hates the blank cell, although I think it is supposed to have balanced